# Runs perfectly manually, but doesn't run as cron job

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, cron

I can perform a task manually, but I can't do the same with cron job.
I am currently using free Heroku cron job.

```
desc "This task is called by the Heroku cron add-on"
task :cron => :environment do    
  if Time.now.hour == 11 # at 11am
    require 'net/http'
    uri = URI('http://pure-spring-2794.herokuapp.com/today')
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
    req.basic_auth 'usernameXXX', 'password***'
    res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) {|http|
      http.request(req)
    } 
  end
end
```

Basically, the cron job hits 'http://pure-spring-2794.herokuapp.com/today', and a certain method is carried out. If I run what the cron job does on rails console, it works perfectly.

Comment: Are you sure the cron is called from heroku side?

Comment: As far as the cron job set up goes, I did all the stuff they instructed me to do. http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cron

Comment: Debug with something else, like it writing to a log to see if it's really fired.

Comment: The Free Heroku CRON is running daily. Are you sure it's running at 11am ?

Comment: I thought Heroku CRON was deprecated. Why not use Scheduler? It'll give you the hourly control you need. Heroku CRON runs daily, and it might not be running at exactly 11 am.